# How to edit child models on one page

Tags: django

How to edit child models on one page with the parent model?

I can display a child form on the parent view, create a child record, and display it on the same parent view page. This is because I know the current parent model pk and I can show all child objects for this specific parent model.

My current view looks like this:

```
def parent_detail(request, pk):
    parent = get_object_or_404(models.parent, pk=pk)
    children = child.objects.filter(parent=pk) # I call a function that creates a new child by using forms
    return render(request, 'parents/detail.html', {
        'parent': parent, 'children': children, 'form': form
    })
```

If I do something like this in templates

```
{% for child in children %}
   {{ child.text }}
   <form method="post" action="" novalidate>
   {% csrf_token %}
   <button type="submit" method="POST">Edit this child</button>
{% endfor %}
```

I see the “Edit” button previous to each child entry, but I failed to associate each “edit” button with the entry. I would like to have the ability to edit the parent model and its children on the same view.

Thank you in advance! I spent 2 days on it.. I will really appreciate if you help me

UPDATE: I used inlineformset_factory. I can include and edit records. However, I can't delete them. Django didn't show any errors. Payload showed that Django sends the correct POST request but nothing happened.

```
[..]  'child_set-0-child_text': ['message'], 'child_set-0-DELETE': ['on']   [..]
```

I found that formset is valid.. any ideas? There are many different issues. I will create a new project tomorrow and I will let you know.

Comment: [Inline model formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets)

Comment: Thank you for the navigation! I am going to read about inline models.

Comment: Sounds like I will resolve this issue soon with inline model formsets. Cheers!

Comment: Daniel, it works now: I can include an additional answer and edit it. However, when using inlineformset_factory "delete" checkbox appears. This checkbox does not work. I see that Django submits the same payload for a parent model without deleting entries. Do you have any idea on why this happened? No errors, my user is root - it has full rights. I can include a message, edit it, but can't delete

Comment: Post request shows [..] 'answer_set-0-answer_text': ['message'], 'answer_set-0-DELETE': ['on'],  [..]

delete checkbox was on, but nothing happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer was posted by Daniel Roseman:

[Inline model formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets)